# List Bitbucket accounts with failed login attempts / count using API

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-api

Is it possible to get a list with users from our Bitbucket server that has information about failed login attempts?

Can I use the API? Query the database? Code snippets?

Answer (score 0):

This information can be obtained in the application logs. Usually at `$BITBUCKET_HOME/log`.

You can see more about this topic at Bitbucket's [Knowledge Base](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/how-to-find-out-failed-login-attempts-779171688.html)